# Automated Deployement of ASP.Net Website with a Continuous Deployment model

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web

For our company websites we develop in a style that would be most accurately called Continuous Deployment (http://toni.org/2010/05/19/in-praise-of-continuous-deployment-the-wordpress-com-story/)

We have a web farm and every site is located on two servers for fail over purposes.  We wish to automate the process of deploying to our dev server, test server, and prod servers.  Out websites are ASP.Net websites (not web applications) so we don’t do builds, we just push the pages.  We generally change our main site anywhere from 2-20 times a day depending on many variables.  These changes can be simple text/html changes to adding new pages/functionality.

Currently we use TFS for our source control, and each site is its own repository.  We don’t have branches, you manually push your changes to dev (we develop on local machines) when it needs to be reviewed, then after sign off you check in your changes and push them to prod manually (this ensures that the source files are what is actually on prod and merges happen right then).  Obviously there is a lot of room for error in here and it happens, infrequently, where a dev forgets a critical file and brings down the entire site.

It seems that most deployment tools are built upon a build process, which isn’t something we are likely to move to since we need to be extremely agile in meeting our business needs.  What we’d really like, we think, is something like the following:

1. Dev gets latest version of website from source control, which is essentially a copy of production
2. Dev does work on his own box.
3. When it is ready to be reviewed by task owner he creates some form of changeset (either checking in the change or something else) and a tool would then push that change to dev
4. After review (and further possible changes) dev then is able to have the tool push all the changes for this task to test (UAT)
5. After this sign off the changes are automatically pushed to prod and checked into the prod branch, or whatever, for anyone else to get

We’ve toyed around with the idea of having three branches of the code in TFS, but we aren’t sure how you would pull from one branch (prod) but check in to a dev branch (none of us are TFS gurus).

So, how have other people handled this scenario?  We are not wedded to TFS as a source control provider if there is something out there that would do what we wanted, nor do we require a vertical solution, we are more than happy to plug in different components as long as they can be plugged in, or even develop our own if we have to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do this with TFS, but I've successfully done what you're describing with Mercurial, and it works pretty well.

With Mercurial (I'd assume Git is the same way), you can pull from one repo, and push to another. So you'd pull from Prod, do your change, commit locally, push to Dev, and then whenever you're happy, push the changesets into Prod (either from Dev or from Local, doesn't matter).

To get started, you'd have a Prod repo, then clone it into a Dev repo - both of these are on your server. At this point they're identical.

TortoiseHG on Windows gives you the ability to easily choose which repository you're synchronizing with. You can keep both the Prod and Dev repos in your list, and decide which one to use when it's time to pull or push.

Comment: Actually I don't see a way to do this with TFS, but we will look into Mercurial.  Thanks for the tip